# Is there an axiomatic approach to ordinal arithmetic?

Tags: reference-request, ordinals, axioms

I've always wondered, is there an axiomatic approach to the arithmetic of ordinal numbers?

If so, I imagine it would be on par with set theory in terms of its proof-theoretic strength.

Comment: I know ordinal arithmetic exists and it follow the Peano arithmetic axioms http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ordinal_arithmetic.
For example here http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Peano_axioms wikipedia says that the ordinal numbers (defined bye von Neumann in ZF) are a model of Peano arithmetic axioms.
Here another link maybe can be intresting for you.http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Set-theoretic_definition_of_natural_numbers

Comment: @MphLee, I don't get that... how can the ordinals satisfy the axioms of Peano arithmetic, when after all Peano arithmetic has an induction schema?

Comment: I'm not very expert for that i gave you links about the connection betwen ordinals and axioms of peano arithmetic.But I do not have enough knowledge to give you an answer.

Comment: @MphLee: Your comment is not correct.

Comment: @user18921: Could you explain your question? What do you mean *precisely* by an axiomatic approach to ordinal arithmetic? Do you already know that ordinal sum and product are decategorifications of sum and product of well-orders?

Comment: @MartinBrandenburg i can remove it without problems, anyways I'm intrsted for a real answer becase all i found about the relation between ordinal arithmetic and his axiomatization was in wikipedia, i was here only because I was unsure too about this question (that I find very intresting), I hope in some clarification.

Comment: @MartinBrandenburg, a list of first and/or second order sentences, axiomatizing ordinal addition, multiplication, exponentiation. If the list is infinite, it should be generated by an effective procedure. An axiomatization of the category of ordinals would also be of interest.

Comment: And if the theory is second-order, it should really be categorical.

Comment: It was my understanding (I'm not an expert on this topic) that axiomatic developments of ordinal arithmetic are given in texts on proof theory, at least those that deal with the topic of *ordinal analysis* such as **Proof Theory: The First Step into Impredicativity** by Wolfram Pohlers, **Proof Theory** by Gaisi Takeuti, and **Proof Theory** by Kurt Schütte.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

See [*A Formalization of the Theory of Ordinal Numbers*](https://www.jstor.org/stable/2269620) by Gaisi Takeuti in  The Journal of Symbolic Logic, Vol. 30, No. 3 (Sep., 1965), pp. 295-317.

> Although Peano's arithmetic can be developed in set theories, it can
>   also be developed independently. This is also true for the theory of
>   ordinal numbers... In this paper we shall develop *the theory of
>   ordinal numbers in the first order predicate calculus with equality* as
>   an extension of Peano's arithmetic. This theory will prove to be easy
>   to manage and fairly powerful in the following sense: If A is a
>   sentence of the theory of ordinal numbers, then A is a theorem of our
>   system if and only if the natural translation of A in set theory is a
>   theorem of Zermelo-Fraenkel set theory. It will be treated as a
>   natural extension of Peano's arithmetic. The latter consists of axiom
>   schemata of primitive recursive functions and mathematical induction,
>   while the theory of ordinal numbers consists of axiom schemata of
>   primitive recursive functions of ordinal numbers, of transfinite
>   induction, of replacement and of cardinals. The latter three axiom
>   schemata can be considered as extensions of mathematical induction.

Answer (score 5):

I haven't seen explicit axioms used before, but I belive the following should be trivially sufficient to start with:

Let s(x) be the successor function. s, <, +, * are taken as primitive, alongside = and the axioms of equality 
Define Lim(x) as ~(∃z)(S(z)=x) [for simplicity, 0 is taken as a limit ordinal]
Define NextLim(x,y) as Lim(y)&(∀z)( z > x & Lim(z) => (z > y)v(z=y))
Define nextlim(x) as the y such that NextLim(x,y)
Define Anc(x,y) as nextlim(x) > y & Lim(x) 
Define anc(x) for the y such that Anc(x,y), or 0 if there is no such y
Define ω as nextlim(0)
Axioms
1a. (∃y)( y < nextlim(x) & y = s(x) )
1b. (∃y)(y = nextlim(x))
2a. Lim(0)
2b. ~∃x(0 = nextlim(x))
3a. s(x)=s(y) => x=y
3b. anc(x)=anc(y) 
3c. anc(x)=anc(s(x))
3d. nextlim(x)=nextlim(s(x))
4a. x < y & y < z => x < z
4b. x < y & y < z => x = z
4c. x < y v y < x v x=y
4d. x < s(x) & x < nextlim(x)
4e  x < y => s(x) < s(y)  
5a. x+0=x 
5b. x+(s(y))=s(x+y) 
5c. x + nextlim(y) = nextlim(x+y) 
6a. x*0=0
6a. s(x*y) = (x*y)+x 
6b. x * nextlim(y) = nextlim(x*y) 
7a. (b < a) & (∀x < a)((P(x) & P(anc(x))) => P(s(x))) => P(b) 
7b. (∀y)((∀x)(x < y => P(x)) => P(y))) => P(a)

The basic intuition is to limit the induction scheme to induction under an ordinal with regard to successor, and then add transfinite recursion. When quantifiers are bounded under ω, Peano Arithmetic should follow trivially from the above axioms.

I may have forgotten one or two (possibly for the relation of nextlim and <), and I highly suspect that there are a few redundant ones, but the basic intuition is to limit the induction scheme to induction under an ordinal with regard to successor, and then add unbounded transfinite recursion. I believe exponentiation is definable from + and * in this context, but I might be wrong. In that case, just add explicit axioms for exponentiation. In either case, once exponentiation is defined, you should be able to use use a transfinite Godel numbering to give a model of the theory of types. Once that is done, you can manipulate that model to provide axioms for larger and larger ordinals.

I threw these together somewhat hastily, so if anyone spots any errors, I blame someone else.

Answer (score -1):

Ordinal arithmetic falls out of manipulations in set theory. You can define order and the ordinal operations in basic set theory and then prove things about these operations.

How big the ordinals you can construct depends on which axioms of ZF you allow or add. The theory behind this is called [Reverse Mathematics](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Reverse_mathematics).

The intent of Reverse Mathematics is to show which theorems of (nominally non-logical) mathematics are of equivalent strength, that is, can allow you to prove each other, and what logical axioms fit.

Comment: I have no idea what you mean to say. The usual way of reading what you wrote makes the first sentence false. Besides, reverse mathematics is not the right framework here. If you feel it is, you need to explain why second-order arithmetic suffices for the task at hand. And still this does not address the question of proof-theoretic strength.